# Youtube 2.0 Playback Error on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, youtube

Relevant info:
iPhone 5, ios 6.1 (jailbroken)

Updated to latest version of youtube app (2.0.0.70=804) which I *think* initially was working. Then recently I used google's "sign out of concurrent sessions" feature to sign out of about 500 logins across various devices. I have 2-factor-auth on also.

Anyway, now I can't play any videos on the phone.  Signed out or signed in.  Any video I try to play just shows me a black screen with "Playback Error" and the smug cat logo.  I tried the things I found on their iOS help page which included changing network settings, trying wifi or LTE, and signing out, uninstalling, then reinstalling.

Nothing doing.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.   Did a [hard reset](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1430) while I was signed out of youtube fixed the problem.  Working again whether signed in or not.